# Button_click before Page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, postback

I am working with a generic list in a simple page containing a user control.

I populate this list by using Session variable. This Session variable is set in my Button_click event.

When user click on the button the session variable is set and a postback happens.The problem is that the Page_load is called before the Button_clicked event...As we know it's the standard page's lifecycle.

Finally,my generic List is not updated because the session variable is set after page_load.

EDIT:My session variable is set up in a function handled by a delegate on button click of my User Control.

Is there a solution to prevent this? Is there a solution to keep value of this list accross many postback withtou using session variable?

Thank you for your help,

Quentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution: I have to override the Pre_render function of the main page.
Indeed,the lifecycle is: Page_load->Button_click->Page_PreRender.

So in my Pre_render function I can get my Session variable setted up and use it as I want.

From what I understood,the Pre_Render event is often used for initializing value of controls just before they are displayed on the Page.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In the Click event, you should do three things:

1. Save your generic list to Session.
2. Save a cookie like flag (can be a session value) signaling that the list has been saved.
3. `Resonse.Redirect(Request.RawURL)` Redirect to the same page.

And in the Page_Load event you should do something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["MyFlag"] != null)
        {
            //Perform whatever you need to do with your already saved generic list in Session
            Session["MyFlag"] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to store a complex object like a generic list across postbacks Session is your friend. If you need to store just a value you can use a cookie or a ASP.HiddenField, but for this you are better using Session.

Comment: Hi, your solution seems to be good.However, it will trigger other problems.Indeed, all other variables that the user entered in the form of the main page will be forgotten with the Response.Redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set your session inside of:

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
    // your session setting here (or method)
}
```

So it will keep the value across the postback without setting it with every postback.

Also you can declare a method that you can easily call from the !IsPostback or your cick event.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try moving your code from Page_Load to Page_PreRender which will fire after your button click event.  This should solve the issue you are having.

Comment: Not if controls such as LinkButtons are created.